# How do i split a string twice in rust?

Tags: string, rust, split

i need split String "fooo:3333#baaar:22222"
Firstly by # secondary by :

and result must be <Vec<Vec<&str, i64>>>
for the first step (split by #) i came up with

```
.split('#').collect::<Vec<&str>>()
```

but I can't think of a solution for the second step

Comment: So. I made this code:  <br/>  
`.split('#').map(|a| a.split(':').collect::<Vec<&str>>());`   
and i get ["fooo", "3333"], ["baaar", "2222"]   
How can i convert "3333" into i64 ?

i can't d

Comment: [`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) is usually used for that.

Comment: Is it always `a:b#i:j#x:y` or can it also be `a:b#i#x:y:z`

Comment: I'm still learning  rust and in this example there can be no other values.   
Also, I'm sorry that I can't format my comments nicely. I'm trying, but I'm too dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Vec<&str, i64>` is not a thing, so I assume you meant `(&str, i64)`

You can create that by splitting first, then mapping over the chunks.

```rust
    let v = s
        .split('#') // split first time
        // "map" over the chunks and only take those where
        // the conversion to i64 worked
        .filter_map(|c| { 
            // split once returns an `Option<(&str, &str)>`
            c.split_once(':')
                // so we use `and_then` and return another `Option`
                // when the conversion worked (`.ok()` converts the `Result` to an `Option`)
                .and_then(|(l, r)| r.parse().ok().map(|r| (l, r)))
        })
        .collect::<Vec<(&str, i64)>>();
```

References:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map
https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/primitive.str.html#method.split_once
https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok

Answer (score 0):

You can call a closure on each element of an iterator returned by the first split and split inside closure and push values to the vector.

```
    let mut out = Vec::new();
    s.split('#').for_each(|x| out.push(x.split(":").collect::<Vec<&str>>()));
```

Comment: You can also just do `.map(|x| x.split(":").collect::<Vec<&str>>()).collect::Vec<_>()`

Comment: very cool solution! Thanks for the answer!
But there is one but. The number must be converted to i64 from the string.

Comment: Yes even `.map` approach works. If you want to store string and i64 then it can not be a vec, it should be a tuple or something.

Comment: YES! Since I'm a dumb newbie, I completely forgot that a vector can only store one type of data.
It turns out I need a vector with a tuple!
sorry for misleading